# Use prop value in another prop reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I've got a banner component that has a message field - in this case a welcome message.

One of the props is called `'headline'`, in which you can enter your message. Currently I'm using the message 'Hi Joe, welcome to your account', but I'd like to pull the name from another prop.

This is what I currently have in the ReactDOM.render:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(PriorityComponents.HeaderBanner, {
      desktopImage:{},
      mobImage:{},
      altText:'alt test goes here',
      isLeftAligned:true,
      userName: 'Joe',
      headline: 'Hi Joe, welcome to your account',
      label: ''
    }), document.getElementById("HeaderBanner"));
```

The headline is being called in as follows:

`<Editable tag="h1" className="headerBanner__body__headline" html={article.headline} />`

I thought I might be able to use the following: 
`userName: 'Joe',
headline: 'Hi ' + userName + ', welcome to your account'`

This seems to be breaking the component! Any idea how to reference the username in the headline prop?

Comment: please provide a code sample. also please share what you've tried to do.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. It doesn't seem like you are using JSX. I believe it might even be a duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/218196), but at the moment it's unclear what the context of your code example is.

Comment: I've updated with a bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using an placeholder which will be replaced when rendering:

```
userName: 'Joe',
headline: 'Hi {userName}, welcome to your account'
```

in `render()`

```
return <div>
  <div className="headline">
      {this.props.headline.replace('{userName}', this.props.userName)}
  </div>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [ES6 Template literals](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_template-literals.html#sec_introduction-template-literals) like this:

```
const username = 'Joe';

// While sending props
username: {username} 
headline: {`Hi ${username}, welcome to your account`}
```

Support for [es6 object shorthand](https://github.com/facebook/jsx/issues/23) in react still wip so you can't use it for username just yet.